# Search on multiple Vlook up columns or Index on Google Sheets or Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have this data in Google Sheets

```
name    Id1      Id2       Id3
Simon   ID0002             ID0001   
Bob              ID003
Roger   ID004              ID005
Jim     IDO006
```

How can i do a multiples Vlookup or Index search to return the column name?

```
Searchkey   Name
ID0001     Simon
ID0002     Simon
ID003       Bob
ID004      Roger
ID005      Roger
IDO006      Jim
```

Heres my link : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VSP1OiuXTf4CxEKVC-KIKp98EU9jTsj9VOTXz7GxSC8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Check my answer and your google sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SUMPRODUCT()` with `INDEX()` function. Try below-

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$5,SUMPRODUCT(ROW($B$1:$D$5)*($B$1:$D$5=H4)))
```

[image]

> This will work both on `Excel` and `Google Sheet`.

Comment: What i want to return is from an =QUERY(importRange) and and Im also looking for match on array formula which not working with this formula... Any workaround ?

Comment: But you do not mention it to your post. What you are using. Please edit your question and include your efforts.

Comment: Yes i tought it will work with your formula (which does). but dosent on arrays and querys data. Let me create another example

Comment: @SimonGIS changing your question once a neat answer is posted, is not really fair, someone put effort into answering your original question. Also, edit your original question so it is clear is better than dumping important info in comments. You did ask for a solution using index() and made no mention of query().